# Core dumped after successful f2py LAPACK call

Tags: python, numpy, lapack, f2py

I'm using f2py to call a LAPACK routine from python (namely DGEQP3). I have first created a `pyf` file in order to create a more usable interface.

```
f2py -h dgeqp3.pyf -m dgeqp3 SRC/dgeqp3.f
```

This file now looks like this:

```
!    -*- f90 -*-
! Note: the context of this file is case sensitive.

python module dgeqp3 ! in 
    interface  ! in :dgeqp3
        subroutine dgeqp3(m,n,a,lda,jpvt,tau,work,lwork,info) ! in :dgeqp3:SRC/dgeqp3.f
            integer :: m
            integer :: n
            double precision dimension(lda,0) :: a
            integer intent(hide),depend(a) :: lda=shape(a,0)
            integer intent(in, out), dimension(n), depend(n) :: jpvt
            double precision intent(out), depend(m), dimension(m),  :: tau
            double precision intent(out), depend(lwork), dimension(lwork) :: work
            integer :: lwork
            integer intent(out) :: info
        end subroutine dgeqp3
    end interface 
end python module dgeqp3
```

I build the library like so:

```
f2py -c dgeqp3.pyf SRC/dgeqp3.f -lblas -llapack -latlas
```

I have created the following script to invoke the routine, which seems to be working flawlessly.

```
import dgeqp3
import numpy as np
print(np.version.version)
A = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0])    
jpvt = np.array([0,0,0])
lwork = 10 
j,t,w,i = dgeqp3.dgeqp3(3, 3, A, jpvt, lwork)
```

However, just before the program terminates, I get

```
*** Error in `python': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000002bb8e60 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm using numpy version 1.8.2 and have compiled the DGEQP3 lib from LAPACK 3.5.0, on a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.13.0-43-generic. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to solve this exactly, but I discovered that there is a wrapper for this Fortran function [available in Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lapack.dgeqp3.html#scipy.linalg.lapack.dgeqp3).

```
scipy.linalg.lapack.dgeqp3
```

Moreover, this call just requires the input matrix as an argument, which is quite convenient.